# A person who never appreciates you, no matter how much you help them

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A person who always asks for favours and if you fail/deny for any one breaks the relationship with you, starts bitching behind your back. This person gives respect only to people who say “no” to him at first or bully him or show-off money power.

**Background:** Since I was a small kid I have seen my father helping my jobless uncle (Mom's brother) but he has never thanked him. Instead, he curses behind my father's back but remains sweet in person.

After 30 years,  my uncle has his own family but due to his attitude, he spends most of these years jobless, borrowing money and asking for favours. Few days ago, my father again did him a favour, talked to some guys and set him on a back office work, because my uncle's kids are going to college and often need money to buy expensive clothes and phones.

We learned that uncle has started bitching about my father accusing him of landing him in a shitty job; its lots of work here and people often have to stay late. My cousins are calling asking explanations, I want to reply and will keep it short because they are also like their father.

**I will tell them that your father has been "__this word__" his whole life so go ask your daddy and don't disturb me.**

Excuse me for the story, I had put it just to get closer to the word. It's not like I am sharing family issues on global website.

Comment: "[Ungrateful](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ungrateful)" and its synonyms will fit your meaning.

Comment: Somehow, I think that after you get whatever answer you get, you should go over to [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) and see if there isn't a better way to say this.

Comment: For me, "_this word_" would be *self-absorbed*.

Comment: Best answered here:  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Spencer Oh are you talking about this issue or word? I think about the issue. Sure I'll check, until now I was thinking to stick with one liner because it's useless  to talk to explain, when other party doesnt have empty head but full of shit, immature stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## [ungrateful](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ungrateful)
>
> *from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition*
>
> ***adj.*** Not feeling or exhibiting gratitude, thanks, or appreciation.
>
> ***adj.*** Not agreeable or pleasant; repellent: "I will not perform the ungrateful task of comparing cases of failure” ( Abraham Lincoln).
>
> *from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License*
>
> ***adj.*** not grateful; not expressing gratitude; a dissatisfied person.
>
> *from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English*
>
> ***adj.*** Not grateful; not thankful for favors; making no returns, or making ill return for kindness, attention, etc.; ingrateful.
>
> ***adj.*** Unpleasing; unacceptable; disagreeable.
>
> *from The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia*
>
> - Not grateful; not feeling thankful or showing gratitude for favors; not making returns, or making ill returns, for kindness.
> - Exhibiting ingratitude; characterized by ingratitude: as, ungrateful conduct; ungrateful words.
> - Giving no return or recompense; offering no inducement: as, “th' ungrateful plain,”
> - Unpleasing; unacceptable; disagreeable.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like a noun form for an ungrateful person, the word *ingrate* would work.

It is [defined as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingrate)

> an ungrateful person

Example sentences from the Merriam-Webster site:

> The president seems to divide aides into two groups: those loyal to their masters, and *ingrates.*
>
> Outside of the fake news or politically motivated *ingrates,* people are now starting to recognize the amazing work that has been done by FEMA and our great military.